# Simplify function declaration

Tags: rust

I would like to simplify the declaration of the following function:

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn oper<'a, F>(regex: &str, op: F) -> (Regex, Box<dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> i32 + 'a>)
where F: Fn(i32, i32) -> i32 + 'a
{
    (Regex::new(regex).unwrap(), Box::new(op))
}
```

I tried to replace the `Fn` trait by `F` in the return value, but it raises an error:

```rust
fn oper<'a, F>(regex: &str, op: F) -> (Regex, Box<dyn F>)
where F: Fn(i32, i32) -> i32 + 'a
{
    (Regex::new(regex).unwrap(), Box::new(op))
}
```

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found type parameter `F`
  --> src/lib.rs:5:55
   |
5  |   fn oper<'a, F>(regex: &str, op: F) -> (Regex, Box<dyn F>)
   |                                                         ^ help: a trait with a similar name exists: `Fn`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

How can simplify this declaration to avoid duplication of `Fn(i32, i32) -> i32 + 'a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this technique](https://www.worthe-it.co.za/programming/2017/01/15/aliasing-traits-in-rust.html). In short, define a new trait that requires `Fn(i32, i32) -> i32` and implement it for any type that already implements `Fn(i32, i32) -> i32`:

```rust
use regex::Regex;

// 1. Create a new trait
pub trait MyFn: Fn(i32, i32) -> i32 {}

// 2. Implement it
impl<T> MyFn for T where T: Fn(i32, i32) -> i32 {}

fn oper<'a, F>(regex: &str, op: F) -> (Regex, Box<dyn MyFn + 'a>)
    where F: MyFn + 'a
{
    (Regex::new(regex).unwrap(), Box::new(op))
}
```

Note, however, that this might be less readable than just repeating `Fn(i32, i32) -> i32` in the signature of `oper`.

Comment: Thank you it's working, even if now type inference is a bit less "smarter": when using `oper("...", |a, b| a.pow(b as u32))`, it forces me to add a closure param type: `oper("...", |a: i32, b| a.pow(b as u32))`